# Widget background images missing on second blog excerpt page

Tags: widgets, nextpage

On my main blog page, there are category images on the left-hand side. When I click "next page" at the bottom of the excerpt list, and the second page of excerpts loads, the images are no longer showing up.  The images are coded directly in a widget.  Any idea what I'm missing?

The main blog page:

http://bit.ly/1QCIV8A

The code (note: I changed the theme name in the url to "themename" to preserve anonymity after problem is fixed):

```
<div class="homecat" style="margin-top: 19px; height: 200px; line-height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px; background: url(../wp-content/themes/themename/images/cat-craftideas.jpg); border: none;"><a href="../category/craft-ideas">craft ideas</a></div>
<div class="homecat" style="margin-top: 19px; height: 200px; line-height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px; background: url(../wp-content/themes/themename/images/cat-party.jpg); border: none;"><a href="../category/party">party</a></div>
<div class="homecat" style="margin-top: 19px; height: 200px; line-height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px; background: url(../wp-content/themes/themename/images/cat-printables.jpg); border: none;"><a href="../category/printables">printables</a></div>
```

Comment: What is the widget code? The PHP, not the generated HTML?

Comment: are you familiar with the difference between relative and absolute URLs?

Comment: <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') ||
           !dynamic_sidebar('My new sidebar') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Milo, the domain is going to change today, hopefully, so that's why it isn't absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your browser's error console, you'll see the 404 errors for your background images, which will point to where the issue is.

This URL:

```
../wp-content/themes/themename/images/cat-party.jpg
```

basically says, "go up one directory from the current directory, then from there look in `wp-content`, then `themes`, then `images`, etc..".

That works fine on the front page, but when you navigate to `/page/2/`, the `wp-content` directory can't be found by navigating up one directory. It's looking for your images in:

```
/page/wp-content/themes/themename/images/cat-party.jpg
```

which doesn't exist.

That's why you need to use absolute or root-relative URLs for assets in WordPress, because you can't know the context from where your content will be served, so relative links will often fail.